# T-SQL create table and index in one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to create indexes(no foreign keys and not unique) and table( not a table variable ) with just one SQL statement like this.

```
CREATE TABLE tabind
(
    id          int             identity(1,1) primary key   ,
    birthday    datetime        default getdate()           ,
    some_id     int             INDEX index_name, /*this line causes a sql server error*/
    name        nvarchar(100)
);
```

In fact the equivalent of this statements:

```
CREATE TABLE tabind
(
    id          int             identity(1,1) primary key   ,
    birthday    datetime        default getdate()           ,
    some_id int             ,
    name        nvarchar(100)
);

create index idx_tabind on tabind(some_id);
```

**My SQL Server Version is 2012.**

Thanks.

Comment: yes. try out yourselve

Comment: If in doubt, just check the manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx

Comment: Your link is for SQL Sever 2014 ... my question was for 2012 :)

Comment: @StefanMichev: Click on the `Other versions` link, then select `SQL Server 2012`. I know that it is hard to search by yourself and easier to wait for the perfect solution, but without your effort it will not come. (Just a side note: The `CREATE TABLE` statement did not change a lot)

Comment: I already checked the older versions ... imho this is not possible at least for sql 2012 version!

Comment: It looks like older versions' documentation can still be found.  If you dig a little further, there is a section for archived previous versions that goes all the way back to SQL 2005.  [SQL 2012 CREATE TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms174979%28v%3dsql.110%29)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the in-line index declaration is 2014 only.

This actually creates the same index though.

```
CREATE TABLE tabind
  (
     id       INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     birthday DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
     some_id  INT,
     NAME     NVARCHAR(100),
     CONSTRAINT index_name UNIQUE (NAME, id)
  );
```

SQL Server silently [makes non unique non clustered indexes unique](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/03/07/more-about-nonclustered-index-keys.aspx) by adding in the clustered index key (implicitly created by the PK in your case)

Comment: Thanks, i was 99% sure about the NO :)